# Erro - Update de senha bcrypt mongoose sem encriptação

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

Não estou conseguindo encriptar minha senha durante um update usando bcrypt no mongoose. A senha é alterada sem problemas, mas sem encriptação.

Segue o schema:

```
var mongoose= require('mongoose');
module.exports= function(){
var schema= mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    senha:{
        type: String,
        required: true, 
        bcrypt: true
    },

});

schema.plugin(require('mongoose-bcrypt'));
return mongoose.model('Usuario', schema);}
```

Segue trecho do controller:

```
controller.updateUsuario= function(req, res){

    var Usuario= app.models.usuario;

    var _id= req.params.id;

    // Atualização de cadastro
    if(_id){
        Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, req.body).exec()
            .then(
                function(usuario){
                    res.json(usuario);
                },
                function(erro){
                    console.error(erro);
                    res.status(500).json(erro);
                }
            );
    }};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `findByIdAndUpdate`, assim como a maior parte das funções da família `update` do mongoose, não instanciam o `Model` e por isso, não executam:

- defaults
- setters
- validators
- middleware

Há uma nota sobre isso no final da documentação do método `findByIdAndUpdate` [1]. O recomendado é substituir com:

```
Model.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) ..
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.save(callback);
})
```

Claro, aí você está fazendo duas queries e fica a seu critério se isso é um problema ou não. Suponho que quando está atualizando o usuário, já o autenticou e portanto já tem o seu documento na memória. Nesse caso, você não teria que dar esse `find`, só arrumar um jeito de dividir a instância usada na autenticação com a rota.

Usando `passport`, em geral, há uma instância do documento (ou o que quer que seja passado para `passport.deserializeUser na propriedade`req.user`.

[1] - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Answer (score 1):

Sou iniciante, mas acredito que o codigo abaixo te ajudaria:

controller.updateUsuario= function(req, res){

```
var Usuario= app.models.usuario;
var _id = req.body._id;
var dados = {
        "nome" : req.body.nome,
        "email" : req.body.email
};

// Atualização de cadastro
if(_id){
    Usuario.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, dados).exec()
        .then(
            function(usuario){
                res.json(usuario);
            },
            function(erro){
                console.error(erro);
                res.status(500).json(erro);
            }
        );
}};
```